# using the facebook graph api to get status messages in a range

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using /statuses to get status messages for a user successfully using the "limit" parameter. Is there a way to get status messages for a date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the since and until parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

https://graph.facebook.com//statuses?access_token="&fields=message,from,id&since=""&until="NEW_TIME_STAMP"&limit="

here, by giving "fields" you can reduce the data being returned,  using "limit" you can limit the number of status updates returned .. since and until shall have time in UNIX_TIME_STAMP format